# Response code:400 Response message:Bad Request Jmeter api testing with JIRA with POST method

Tags: api, testing, jmeter

When try to create issue in Jira using the JMeter API with POST method, it does not allow to create issue and it shows error below.

I uploaded my all configuration image.

Can anybody correct me?

Thanks in advance.

#### Error message:

```
2020-12-27 19:48:35,841 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.IOException: Server 
returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://learntestapi.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue
2020-12-27 19:48:35,841 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned 
HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://learntestapi.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue
```

#### Screenshots (2 images attached)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using an incorrect URL, i.e. it has to be:

```
/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/QA/issuetypes/{issueTypeId}
```

to identify the `issueTypeId` you need to first execute call to the following endpoint:

```
/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/QA/issuetypes
```

then choose an appropriate issue type and substitute it in the first request.

More information: [Jira REST API examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#creating-an-issue-examples)

Also make sure that your [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) is configured to send [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)

Comment: use this path /rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/QA/bug
but i get the the following following response

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>404</status-code><message>null for uri: https://learntestapi.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/QA/bug</message></status>

then use /rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/QA/bug/10009
But show the same response

Can you please give me direction ?
i am new in Jmeter